# 3 clickable dropdowns do not close when clicked anywhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

Many thanks for the help on my last question..... but i have a small issue now with the next step.

being new to coding and script i found this button on W3 and it suited my purpose so that's why i have used it, however...... i've managed to get the 3 different buttons to go to the 3 different sections, however the lead on issue is that the top 2 buttons do not close when clicking anywhere else on the page.... but the bottom button does.   this is the code....  Can anyone suggest script to close the top two? i have looked on here and have tried different solutions but none seem to work.

(I have removed many many lines of links for ease in pasting)

the webpage is https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/history.html  if that helps with a solution.

thanks in advance
Chris

```
<br>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn1 {
  background-color: #005eb8;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 86px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn1:hover, .dropbtn1:focus {
  background-color: #004a90;
}

.dropdown1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 91px;
  background-color: #f4f7f8;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 440px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content1 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown1 a:hover {background-color: #005eb8; color:white;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown1">
  <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="dropbtn1">--- Select ---</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content1">
<a class="links" href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2019-20r.html">2019-20</a>
<a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2018-19r.html">2018-19</a>
<a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/1890-91r.html">1890-91</a>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction1() {
             document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn1')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content1");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
 </script>

</body>
</html>
<br>

<br>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn2 {
  background-color: #005eb8;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 86px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
  background-color: #004a90;
}

.dropdown2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 91px;
  background-color: #f4f7f8;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 440px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2 a:hover {background-color: #005eb8; color:white;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown2">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">--- Select ---</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2">
<a class="links" href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2019-20t.html">2019-20</a>
<a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2018-19t.html">2018-19</a>
<a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/1890-91t.html">1890-91</a>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
<br>

<br>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn3 {
  background-color: #005eb8;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 86px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn3:hover, .dropbtn3:focus {
  background-color: #004a90;
}

.dropdown3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 91px;
  background-color: #f4f7f8;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 440px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content3 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown3 a:hover {background-color: #005eb8; color:white;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown3">
  <button onclick="myFunction3()" class="dropbtn3">--- Select ---</button>
  <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content3">
<a class="links" href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2019-20s.html">2019-20</a>
<a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2018-19s.html">2018-19</a>
<a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/1890-91s.html">1890-91</a>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction3() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn3')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content3");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
<br>
```

Comment: The `html` tag should only exist once per page. You have multiple in your example. Is there a reason for this, or are you trying to show us multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your example for the sake of time, but this should get you started. There's **a lot** that can be optimized here, but that's too much to get into now.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
        toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function myFunction1() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        function myFunction2() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function( event ) {
            
            const et = event.target;
            if ( !et.matches( '.dropbtn1' ) || !et.matches( '.dropbtn2' ) || et.matches( 'html') ) {
            
                let selector = '';
                if ( et.matches( '.dropbtn1' ) )
                    selector = '.dropdown-content2';
                else if ( et.matches( '.dropbtn2' ) )
                    selector = '.dropdown-content1';
                else
                    selector = "div[class^='dropdown-content']";

                let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll( selector );
                for ( let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++ ) {

                    let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

```css
/* DropButton 1 */
    .dropbtn1 {
        background-color: #005eb8;
        color: white;
        margin-left: 86px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 17px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dropbtn1:hover, .dropbtn1:focus {
        background-color: #004a90;
    }
    .dropdown1 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content1 {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 91px;
        background-color: #f4f7f8;
        min-width: 50px;
        height: 440px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown-content1 a {
        color: black;
        padding: 1px 6px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown1 a:hover {background-color: #005eb8; color:white;}

    /* DropButton 2 */
    .dropbtn2 {
        background-color: #005eb8;
        color: white;
        margin-left: 86px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 17px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
        background-color: #004a90;
    }
    .dropdown2 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content2 {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 91px;
        background-color: #f4f7f8;
        min-width: 50px;
        height: 440px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown-content2 a {
        color: black;
        padding: 1px 6px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown2 a:hover {background-color: #005eb8; color:white;}

    /* Misc */
    .show {display: block;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="dropdown1">
    <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="dropbtn1">--- Select ---</button>
        <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content1">
            <a class="links" href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2019-20r.html">2019-20</a>
            <a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2018-19r.html">2018-19</a>
            <a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/1890-91r.html">1890-91</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown2">
        <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">--- Select ---</button>
        <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2">
            <a class="links" href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2019-20t.html">2019-20</a>
            <a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/2018-19t.html">2018-19</a>
            <a class=”links” href="https://www.glossopnorthendafc.co.uk/1890-91t.html">1890-91</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```